# Playbook task for Find & replace nested key values

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

ip_details.yaml

```
---
ip1:
  image:
    name: <ip input> # ip address 1 

ip2:
  config:
    range: 192.0.0.0
  image:
    name: <ip input> # ip address 2
  id:
    username:  # ip username
    password:  # ip Password
```

fetch_value.yml

```
ip1_image_name: 192.0.0.1
ip2_image_name: 192.0.0.2
ip_username: user@123
ip_password: pass@123
```

The task is to write one new update_ip.yml task for finding the ip_details.yaml file path and replacing/updating the ip input and id username and password.

I tried :

update_ip.yml

```
  - lineinfile:
        path: values.yml
        regexp: "{{ item.regexp }}"
        line: "{{ item.line }}"
        backrefs: true
      loop:
        - {regexp: '^(\s*)ip1.image.name: <user ip>(.*)$', line: '\1name: {{ ip1_image_name }}\2'}
        - {regexp: '^(\s*)ip2.image.name: <user ip>(.*)$', line: '\1name: {{ ip2_image_name }}\2'}
        - {regexp: '^(\s*)ip2.id.username:\s+.*?(\s+#.*)$', line: '\1username: {{ ip_username }}\2'}
        - {regexp: '^(\s*)ip2.id.password:\s+.*?(\s+#.*)$', line: '\1password: {{ ip_password }}\2'}
```

Final expectation : ip_details.yml

```
---
ip1:
  image:
    name: 192.0.0.1 # ip address 1 

ip2:
  config:
    range: 192.0.0.0
  image:
    name: 192.0.0.2 # ip address 2
  id:
    username: user@123 # ip username
    password: pass@123 # ip Password
```

Comment: difficult to understant your logic..between the start file and the end file...its very unclear, could you precise..?

Comment: I have added more details can you please check now . @Frenchy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suggest you to use a [template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html) module:

1. create your template file `ip_details.j2` in folder `templates` (same level than your playbook)

   ```
    ---
    ip1:
      image:
        name: {{ ip1_image_name }} # ip address 1 

    ip2:
      config:
        range: 192.0.0.0
      image:
        name: {{ ip2_image_name }} # ip address 2
      id:
        username:  {{ ip_username }} # ip username
        password:  {{ ip_password  }} # ip Password
   ```
2. create playbook:

   ```
        - name: testplaybook jinja2
          hosts: localhost
          gather_facts: no
          vars:
            ip1_image_name: 192.0.0.1
            ip2_image_name: 192.0.0.2
            ip_username: user@123
            ip_password: pass@123

          tasks:
            - name: template
              template:
                src: ip_details.j2
                dest: ip_details.yml
   ```
3. result in `ip_details.yml`:

   ```
    ---
    ip1:
      image:
        name: 192.0.0.1 # ip address 1 

    ip2:
      config:
        range: 192.0.0.0
      image:
        name: 192.0.0.2 # ip address 2
      id:
        username:  user@123 # ip username
        password:  pass@123 # ip Password
   ```